# Server not receiving message properly?

Tags: c, linux, networking

I am new to networking in C and I have been trying to make a server retrieve a message from a client, however the write message continues to fail. When I made this I basically tried to modify a program which receives messages from a server to send it. This is the server code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define PORTNUM 1887

int server() {
  char msg[101];

  struct sockaddr_in dest;
  struct sockaddr_in serv;
  int mysocket;
  socklen_t socksize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

  memset(&serv, 0, sizeof(serv));

  serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
  serv.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);

  mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
  bind(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serv, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

  listen(mysocket, 2); 
  int consocket = accept(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize);
  int len;

  while (consocket) {
    printf("Incoming connection from %s - recieving welcome\n", inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
    len = recv(mysocket, msg, 100, 0); 
    msg[len] = '\0';
    if (len > 0) printf("%s %d\n", msg, len);
    consocket = accept(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize);
  }
  close(consocket);
  close(mysocket);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main() {
  return server();
}
```

And this is the client.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>


#define MAXREC 100
#define PORTNUM 1887

int getMessage() {
  char buffer[] = "Hello Fish!\n";
  int len, mysocket;
  struct sockaddr_in dest;

  mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
  dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
  dest.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
  dest.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);

  connect(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
  printf("%s\n", buffer);
  write(mysocket,"45", strlen("45"));


  close(mysocket);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main() {
  return getMessage();
}
```

Initially I tried sending the buffer message then I switched to try using a constant to see if that would help.

Comment: Notice that standard *C* don't know about networking. You probably are on Linux or some other Posix compliant system. So please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Why do you call `accept` in a loop after only one message? A given TCP connection is generally used for several messages....

Comment: Deos the "real" code also fully ignores testing whether the various system calls failed?

Comment: Also please closely read the man-pages for `read()`/`recv()`/`write()`/`send()` and learn that at least for sockets those functions do not necessarily read/receive/write/send as much bytes as they were told to, but few. So looping around such calls counting until all data or a terminator had been received/sent is a good idea, not to say an essential necessity.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch this is not supposed to be a finished application, I was just trying to figure out how it works, so this simple program is just sending one message

Comment: @alk yeah the code i borrowed from left out all the tests for clarity, I plan to add them in later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
len = recv(mysocket, msg, 100, 0);
```

on the server should be

```
len = recv(consocket, msg, 100, 0);
```

[accept](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept) returns a handle to the new connection so you need to read that for client messages.